# How do I save (add) my STS temporary credentials in my AWS credentials file?

Tags: python, file, amazon-web-services, text

I have generated the temp credentials but I want to upload credentials, which are in array, to `~/.aws/credentials` with profile name to file through boto3 python . Tried with file operation did not succeed.

```
import boto
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
import subprocess
import os
import sys

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.sts import STSConnection

# Prompt for MFA time-based one-time password (TOTP)
mfa_TOTP = raw_input("Enter the MFA code: ")

sts_connection = STSConnection(profile_name="dev-yudw")

tempCredentials = sts_connection.get_session_token(
    duration=3600,
    mfa_serial_number="arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:mfa/yudi",
    mfa_token=mfa_TOTP
)

print tempCredentials.access_key
print tempCredentials.secret_key
print tempCredentials.session_token

lines_of_text = [
    "aws_access_key_id=" + str(tempCredentials.access_key) + "\n", 
    "aws_secret_access_key=" + str(tempCredentials.secret_key)" + "\n", 
    "security_token=" + str(tempCredentials.session_token) + "\n"
]
print str(tempCredentials.access_key)
```

Here any file handling or boto 3 function to upload this array values.
If already exits, need to replace the profile in `~/.aws/credentials`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking: "How do I upload a file to S3 using STS temporary credentials?" OR "How do I save (add) my STS temporary credentials in my AWS credentials file?" Please edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: Thank you , Updated

Comment: Now I need main help on How do I save (add) my STS temporary credentials in my AWS credentials file?

Comment: My initial Question Still not accomplished My Temp credentials need to updated in ~/.aws/credentials file with boto3 python or with file handling

Comment: Sorry i am able to complete

Comment: I'd recommend just using the Assume Role Provider instead: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#assume-role-provider